# Monitor.Wait Initially Locked?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, thread-synchronization

**Background**

I am trying to write an application that does the following:

1. I make a method call to `SomeBlockingMethod`.
2. This method calls blocks until I call `SomeUnblockingMethod` from another thread.
3. When `SomeUnblockingMethod` is called, the routine inside of `SomeBlockingMethod` will continue.

Note, the first thing I do will be to call the `SomeBlockingMethod`, and then later on I will call the `SomeUnblockingMethod`. I am thinking about using a `Monitor.Wait/Monitor.Pulse` mechanism to achieve this. The only thing is, when one calls `Monitor.Wait`, you cannot block initally unless the `object` involved has already been locked by something else (or at least not that I know of)... But, I want *blocking* to be the *first* thing I do... So this leads me into my question...

**Question**

Is there some way I can implement `Monitor.Wait` to initially block until a call to `Monitor.Pulse` is made?

Comment: @Sinatr maybe I was confusing enter... Let me give this a try. Will get back to you.

Comment: You want to use overload of [Monitor.Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syehfawa(v=vs.110).aspx), where you can specify timeout (e.g. [Infinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: @Sinatr yes, you are right... Since I block initially, that is a good idea.

Comment: Screw me for deleting first comment, if you don't specify timeout, [then it's `Infinity`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs,8873bad9bee77901). So that *"Monitor.Wait to initially block until a call to Monitor.Pulse"* already happens.

Comment: @Sinatr don't worry about it, and thanks for the advice.

Comment: In general, there are design methods which help avoid using a shared lock and signaling. Perhaps you can elaborate more on *what you're trying to achieve*, maybe we can come up with a solution that doesn't require such locking at all.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks, and yeah somebody else is saying to just use AutoResetEvent.

Comment: A `AutoResetEvent` will still block the calling thread until you signal it. I'm suggesting that there may be solution which don't require that at all.

Comment: Sounds like a Semaphore with an initial count of 0.  Could be the consumer in a producer-consumer scenario.  Question is too vague, it doesn't describe what happens next and whether thread affinity matters.

Comment: @HansPassant There is nothing to "describe" yet... I have two method stubs, one signals the other. That is all... Although, I could have said that.

Comment: Well, no wonder that you don't know how to write the correct code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thought about putting it on Programmers.SE, but it's asking for help with implementation (sort of) so it's more-or-less off-topic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Threading.AutoResetEvent);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) instead.

```
AutoResetEvent ar = new AutoResetEvent(false); // false set initial state as not signaled
```

Then you can use `ar.WaitOne()` to wait and `ar.Set()` to signal waiting processes.

You should use Monitor when you want to protect a resource or you have a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). If you want to have a signaling mechanism then `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent` sounds like a better option.

Comment: So you would not recommend using Monitors at all for this? Why?

Comment: @StevieV, it's just another possible solution. There is no need to switch to `AutoResetEvent` from [lightweight `Monitor`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking), unless you want to [synchronize different processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1717194/1997232).

Comment: I said you can not you must. @StevieV

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the problem, but what you want is already how it works:

```
object _lock = new object();

void SomeBlockingMethod()
{
    lock(_lock)
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);
    ... // here only after pulse
}

void SomeUnblockingMethod()
{
    lock(_lock)
        Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
}
```

Perhaps you are calling `SomeBlockingMethod` from multiple places, then you want to use `PulseAll`. Or perhaps `SomeUnblockingMethod` is called **before** `SomeBlockingMethod`?

Comment: For this, is the unblocking-method able to enter the `lock` region if the blocking-method has already entered the `lock` region? I imagine that the unblocking-method would need to enter the region in order to pulse the blocking-method. Right?

Comment: Lock is released when you call `Monitor.Wait()`, so that other method can obtain lock and pulse. [Read more](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse).